# EXCEL FORMATTING NUMBERS

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

I have been working with my Office 2010 Plus program with no problem, for a long time.
Yesterday I started writing a new Excel spreadsheet and formatted columns for currency with no decimals I Typed the first entry $4.000 and to my surprise in the spreadsheet it showed $4000.0 and no 1000 separator
The same 4200 value was then tried with different cell formats and these were the results:

- General:  4200
- Number, no decimal no thousands:  4200
- Number, 2 decimals:  4200.00
- Number, 2 decimals plus 1000 separator: 4200.0.00
- Currency, 2 decimals: $4200.0.00
- Accounting, no decimals:  $ 4200.0

Yet if I use a previously formatted spread sheet or written in another computer numbers are written as supposed and no errors shown.
I went to Control Center - Programs- Office 2010 and click on Repair. Program was repaired, but same error kept on showing up.
So I reinstalled Office 2010 from my original CD..and the same problem kept showing up.
This proves it is not the program software per se, but some error within the registry that somehow is missed by a re installation.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you used the same exact spreadsheet - the one that is having the problems - on another computer? Also, does the same thing happen with a new unformatted workbook?

Comment: Look in Excel options Advanced what setting for decimal separator and thousand separator also in regional settings

Answer (score 1):

Ricardo, I replicated your issue on the 'Format Cells' panel (Home > Number > Category='Custom') creating Type="(* #,##0.0.00);..." [hard coded 0's]. Your number formatting buttons may be associated with a Custom number type which can be inherited when sharing spreadsheets. Periodically I delete Custom types which I created or inherited and no long need. The 'Delete' key activates for types that can be deleted. Hope it helps.
[image: Excel 2013 Format Cells panel]